# Will a uint8_t array be terminated by null similar to a char array?

Tags: arrays, char, uint8t

I am working on a project where the function will receive a pointer to a uint8_t array. I am to compare the contents of this with that of a pointer to unsigned char data buffer whose size is not known. I was hoping to use string based functions for the comparison.

Hence the doubt has arisen.

Comment: **You** know whether at least one of the buffers is supposed to be null terminated (means is a C string), but **I** don't. It it is the case, use str... functions, if not use mem... functions with a length you know. If no buffer has a delimiter, and if you do not know any length, you have lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider:

```
char    *str1    = "hello";
uint8_t  str2[6] = "hello";
int8_t  *str3    = "hello";

int result1 = strcmp(str1, (char*)str2);
int result2 = strcmp(str1, (char*)str3);
```

Both `result1` and `result2` are `0`, i.e., all the strings are equivalent.